# how to use Amazon SWF internal?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

I would like to try Amazon SWF development on my pc. But, It seems to me that I must register to Amazon AWS cloud in order to use Amazon Simple Workflow. What I need is to run all Amazon stuff in a single machine without the need of Amazon hosted services (or authentication).

The documentation for Amazon Simple Workflow Service is [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/developerguide/swf-dg.pdf).

Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

You could run the workflow locally using the aws test framework. In this case everything (activites and decision workers) will run locally on the instance that you will be running the test framework, only that no swf api will be invoked. So you can test the orchestration logic of the decision worker without needing a aws account.

Comment: Maybe I can test the orchestration logic of the decision worker without needing a aws account; but I don't have any code sample for that. I cloned [aws/aws-sdk-net](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net) repository in order to see how I can test it. There are many Test classes there and every test method of SWF requires AWS account (so that means it works online). I couldn't find a way to do that :(
So @Rohit, do you have any code example ?

Comment: I myself use java for SWF implementation. AWS provides junit integration of the AWS Flow Framework, which does not use the SWF service and runs the workflow all internally. You can check the example for the same at the link below http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/test.html#test.junit

Answer (score 0):

Using cloud services offline doesn't make much sense. You will definitely need to sign up for an AWS account to be able to play with SWF. There is a free tier which should be sufficient for your development.

Comment: yeah; it's free but just for a month though :(

Comment: it's for 12 months I believe, and even after that I wouldn't expect the costs to be significant

Comment: oh yes @michal-klouda; it's for 12 months: my mistake. So the only solution is giving the credit card number I suppose. 
I was expecting to see what they did behind the framework; since they're only giving us the assemblies of API (coming with the AWS SDK).